# Dispatch Group wait stuck forever

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have a function making multiple HTTP requests with Alamofire. I want to wait for all of them to finish in order to return a value. However, it gets stuck at dispatch.wait()

```swift
class func getActionField(fieldid: String, completion: @escaping (_ res: [String: [Double]]) -> Void) {
        var resreturn: [String: [Double]] = ["temperature":[], "humidity":[], "ph":[], "light":[]]
        let dispatch = DispatchGroup()
        dispatch.enter()
        Alamofire.request(url + "aktionsdaten/temperatur/" + fieldid, method: .get).responseJSON{ response in
            resreturn["temperature"] = response.result.value as! NSArray as? [Double] ?? [0.0,0.0]
            dispatch.leave()
        }
        dispatch.enter()
        Alamofire.request(url + "aktionsdaten/light/" + fieldid, method: .get).responseJSON{ response in
            resreturn["light"] = response.result.value as! NSArray as? [Double] ?? [0.0,0.0]
            dispatch.leave()
        }
        dispatch.enter()
        Alamofire.request(url + "aktionsdaten/ph/" + fieldid, method: .get).responseJSON{ response in
            resreturn["ph"] = response.result.value as! NSArray as? [Double] ?? [0.0,0.0]
            dispatch.leave()
        }
        dispatch.enter()
        Alamofire.request(url + "aktionsdaten/feuchtigkeit/" + fieldid, method: .get).responseJSON{ response in
            resreturn["humidity"] = response.result.value as! NSArray as? [Double] ?? [0.0,0.0]
            dispatch.leave()
        }
        dispatch.wait()
        completion(resreturn)
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that `getActionField` is being called on the main queue and the understanding that Alamofire calls its completion blocks on the main queue (bad design in my opinion), you are running into a deadlock since the call to `wait` is now blocking the main queue and none of the calls to `leave` can be made.

You must never use the same thread to call `wait` and `leave`.

The simplest solution is to replace the use of `wait` with `notify`.

```
group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
    completion(resreturn)
}
```

You should avoid the use of `wait` in general. Especially if you are already using a completion handler and there is no need for the method to wait.

Answer (score 3):

You have this all set up correctly, using a completion handler after all your asynchronous tasks are finished. The only problem is that you're using the DispatchGroup pattern incorrectly. Here's the correct pattern (this is pseudocode):

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
group.enter()
queue1.async {
    // ... do task here ...
    group.leave()
}
group.enter()
queue2.async {
    // ... do task here ...
    group.leave()
}
group.enter()
queue3.async {
    // ... do task here ...
    group.leave()
}
// ... more as needed ...
group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
    // finished! call completion handler or whatever
}
```

Comment: Thats what I am using too. Just FYI - the group.enter() calls are called right after the other because the closures return immediately.